# nodejs/npm warning no repostory when I install mongodb and more

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-2013, npm

When I install mongodb I'm getting a long warning list like this:

[image]

Why is this happening? I'm not sure if I can ignore this. Because those warnings look pretty serious. I'm concerned about the fact that it is telling me something about Visual Studio 2013...

I've also uninstalled "Nodejs tools for Visual Studio", and reinstalled Nodejs, but I still get these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore that npm warning, it's basically just telling you that the `repository` field isn't filled out in your `denoapp` module's package.json. If you don't have a repository for the module, you could probably just set it to an empty string or something similar.

As long as the module installs/builds ok, you can usually ignore the compiler warnings (especially if they are V8-related since there's not much you can do about those).

Comment: But why are there warnings about files in the Visual Studio directory? Because Nodejs uses a C/C++ compiler of Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio comes with Microsoft's C/C++ compiler and that is what is used on Windows when compiling node and/or addons.